# How many tetrahedrons an edge belongs to in a Body-Centered Cube Lattice?

Tags: geometry

Body-Centered Cube Lattice, also known as BCC Lattice (shown in the Figure) is a kind of lattice where the body of a cube also contains a vertex. 4 vertices as the figure shows constitute a tetrahedron. All tetrahedrons fill the whole space well without overlapping. 
[image: The BCC lattice is composed of two grids of primal and dual vertices. Each vertex is incident to 14 edges, 36 faces, and 24 tetrahedra]

My question is, how many tetrahedrons an edge belongs to, at the most and least cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those edges drawn in bold black in your figure have dihedral angle $90°$, so you have four tetrahedra around each of them. You should be able to imagine those fairly easily: the four tetrahedrons are images of a single one under $90°$ rotations around that edge.

The ones drawn in red have dihedral angle $60°$, so there will be six tetrahedra around those. I actually computed these $60°$ using coordinates for the points involved. But once you know what to look for, you can perhaps imagine those as well. You can imagine every tetrahedron as being made up from two bold black edges, one between black vertices and one between red ones. Now take a red edge which connects a black and a red vertex. There are six bold black edges incident with each of these two vertices, but only three of them oriented towards the other of these two vertices. So you have three around the black vertex, and three around the red one. You can get all six tetrahedrons associated with a red edge by switching to another bold black edge for the black lattice, then get the next one by switching to another edge for the red lattice. So by alternating between which lattice you switch edge, you get all six tetrahedra.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks for your explanation. @MvG